# Getting data between dates

Tags: c#, sql-server

So, I want to retrieve data between two dates in mssql. I have a table, name is FILES. And I have 2 column, names are NAME, RECORDDATE (nvarchar). When I save my data, I take from raddatetimepicker.text so my value is "22 December 2015 Tuesday".

My query is

```
select * from FILES where RECORDDATE>= '11 January 2015 Saturday' and RECORDDATE<= '24 October 2015 Monday'
```

This query is working but when I change '11 January 2015 Saturday' to '28 January 2015 Tuesday' it is not working. It is so interesting because my query with 21 January also working but when I write 28 January I got 0 rows.

I really stuck and no idea about problem.

**Your answers are true but also others answers are true so I do not know how I can I mark all answers as an answer :) Thanks for that. That is my first project after 1 month self training so do not surprise so much :D**

Comment: You should _never_ store your `DateTime` values as a character. You have [a bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type).

Comment: may be there is no data after 28th January @seodu

Comment: Yeah.. this is gonna be a fun one.  But it is possible.

Comment: Sorry, if you have even no ideas, then things do not look good :(

Comment: All my data in 23 October 2015. Query has to show but I don't know why. @mohan111

Comment: Your data format sucks by the way.  It's not standard so it will be hard to convert.  Do the stored dates look as poorly formatted as the dates you are trying to use as a filter?

Comment: @Seodu I'd really love to see your application run on my German Windows... :-D

Comment: I can send you @ThorstenDittmar :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your comparison, you are comparing strings, not dates.  In [SQL string comparison is done based on alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26080187/sql-string-comparison-greater-than-and-less-than-operators).  In your example, this means that `'28...' > '24...'`.

You should either

- change your database design to store your dates as `DATETIME` values, or
- [CAST your `nvarchar` to `DATETIME`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411072/parse-a-date-from-unformatted-text-in-sql/1411081#1411081)

As a side note, including the weekday is unnecessary to check for a date range so I'd recommend removing it to avoid mistakes.  In fact, it appears that you have a mistake in your example: Tuesday should be Wednesday in your question.

Comment: Your answer is true but also others answers are true so I do not know how I can I mark all answers as an answer :) Thanks for that.

Comment: @Seodu Unfortunately you can not do that, but you can upvote them :-) And *please*, change your data model for your own sanity.

Comment: I'm changing now @ThorstenDittmar :)

Answer (score 1):

*The following is true under the condition that your `RECORDDATE` is actually a `DATETIME` field in the database. You currently store what should be a `DATETIME` as an `NVARCHAR`.* **Stop doing this now and use proper types!**

Any `DateTimePicker` should have a property that returns a `DateTime`. If it does not: dump it and use a proper one. That said, you can store as well as look-up your records properly using parameterized queries.

Inserting will look like this:

```
DateTime recordDate = dtpDate.Value;
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into FILES (NAME, RECORDDATE) VALUES (@name, @recorddate)", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = someName;
    cmd.Parameters.ADd("@recorddate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = recordDate;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Then the lookup query comes down to:

```
DateTime start = dtpStart.Value;
DateTime end = dtpEnd.Value;

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from FILES where RECORDDATE BETWEEN @start and @end", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@start", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = start;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@end", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = end;

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        ...
}
```

Doing it this way solves the following problems:

1. SQL injection possible if you insert parameters using `String.Format` or something similar.
2. Different date formats don't matter, as the .NET will convert the date properly into something SQL server understands

Comment: You could fix the data with persisted calculated columns but I have a feeling with dates formatted like he has their are lots of `SELECT *` queries to contend with.

Comment: Of course I always presume that dates/times are stored in databases using the appropriate types. If that's not the case ... well ... that's what you get.

Comment: My god... I just saw that he actually stores the date in the format as `nvarchar`. Seems I hadn't properly read the question before. Oh well...

Comment: yeah... thought this was gonna be easy didn't you :)

Comment: @MatthewWhited I'm feeling a bit ashamed, really. I read the question as if he had proper data in the database and then wanted to compare against this date string. I always wonder how people come to consider things like that a well designed (or even usable) data model...

Comment: Your answer is true but also others answers are true so I do not know how I can I mark all answers as an answer :) Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you get String comparison, not Date comparison, due to RECORDDATE is NVARCHAR (unicode String).

first string starts with '28..' so its bigger than string that starts with '24', so you got always false and therefore 0 rows.

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1411081/2811743

Comment: Your answer is true but also others answers are true so I do not know how I can I mark all answers as an answer :) Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Due to storing the dates as string you are performing string comparisons, not date comparisons. When you have updated your values your are checking for strings between `28 January 2015 Tuesday` and `24 October 2015 Monday`. Given that the lower value is greater you will never get any rows returned.

If you want to find values between two dates then preferably change your data type to `DateTime`.

If this is not possible then you could cast the column to a `DateTime` e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM FILES 
WHERE RECORDDATE >= CAST('11 January 2015 Saturday' AS DATETIME) 
    AND RECORDDATE <= CAST('24 October 2015 Monday' AS DATETIME)
```

*As a sidenote 28 January 2015 is a Wednesday, not a Tuesday*

A drawback to this approach is that you will not be able to use indexes on the `RECORDDATE` column as the query would be non-SARGable

Comment: Your answer is true but also others answers are true so I do not know how I can I mark all answers as an answer :) Thanks for that.

Comment: @Seodu, generally if the answers are equally helpful then choose the oldest. If a particular answer is more useful, then choose that.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you can fix your data... but based on your example dates here is a CTE that will fix your dates and format your data so it can be filtered.

```
WITH [SubDates] AS (
    SELECT 
        [FILES].*
        ,SUBSTRING([FILES].[RECORDDATE], 0, PATINDEX('%20[0-9][0-9] %', [FILES].[RECORDDATE]) + 4) AS [RECORDDATE_Sub]
    FROM [FILES]
), [AsDates] AS (
    SELECT 
        [SubDates].*
        ,CASE ISDATE([SubDates].[RECORDDATE_Sub])
            WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(DATE, [SubDates].[RECORDDATE_Sub])
            END AS [RECORDDATE_Fixed]
    FROM [SubDates]
)
SELECT * 
FROM [AsDates] 
WHERE 
    [AsDates].[RECORDDATE_Fixed] BETWEEN '11 January 2015' AND '24 October 2015'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select * from FILES where RECORDDATE between STR_TO_DATE('11 January 2015 Saturday',"%d %M %Y %W") and STR_TO_DATE('24 October 2015 Monday',"%d %M %Y %W")
```

Comment: he said sql-server as in MSSQL not MySQL.

Comment: Then you should search for date format conversion in MS-SQL.

Comment: You're here to answer this question not tell him to search. Providing a solution for a different DBMS will confuse the OP even more.

Comment: Ohhhh I don;t know, But the only solution is to convert date format nothing else NO logic. Just one google

Comment: If it is so easy (just one google), what keeps you from providing it as an answer here instead of writing something misleading and then telling him to google the proper solution himself?

Comment: lol... we weren't trying to start a fight just point out that suggesting someone use a function that doesn't exist on their platform isn't going to help clear up their confusion.